# How to download kismet for Tails OS?

Tags: tails

Is it safe to download Kismet for Tails OS?

If so, how do you store that software considering everytime you close Tails it wipes everything clean for the next time you boot up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If so, how do you store that software considering everytime you close
>   Tails it wipes everything clean for the next time you boot up?

Install Tails on a USB stick using [2 USB keys](https://tails.boum.org/install/linux/clone-overview/index.en.html). Once it is installed you can set up persistent storage so when you install software. The next time you reboot, it will automatically reinstall it for you and your saved files are saved in the [encrypted filesystem](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/index.en.html).

Then just `apt-get install kismet`

Is it safe? It probably isn't going to harm your anonymity but since nobody has reported using it on the Tails website, you can take that as being pretty much untested.

Comment: so if not Tails, what Linux-based OS is typically used with kismet in a safe and secure manner?

Comment: Safety and security are all about good practices not just about the quality of the OS. To answer your question though, Kali linux would be the #1 tool for something like kismet. https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/kismet